# Does No Mercy get triggered by Blood Scrivener?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I control the card [No Mercy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNo%20Mercy%5d). The card states that whenever a creature successfully deals damage to me it gets destroyed.

Now let us suppose:

1. I also control [Blood Scrivener](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlood%20Scrivener%5d)
2. I have no cards in hand.
3. I need to draw a card.

Because of Blood Scrivener's ability, I draw 2 cards and I lose 1 life.

Question: Does the loss of life induced by Blood Scrivener count as damage? (And does it cause Blood Scrivener to be destroyed?)

Comment: Related: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11600/what-are-the-differences-between-combat-damage-direct-damage-and-loss-of-life

Comment: Blood scrivener says that you lose life, not that he damages you, so you won't lose the blood scrivener due to the effect of no mercy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Damage is different than life loss.  For players, damage causes life loss.

> 119.3a Damage dealt to a player by a source without infect causes that player to lose that much life

So no, the Blood Scrivener isn't destroyed.

Comment: Yes, damage causes loss of life. But what kind of effect is Blood Scrivener's ability? If it is not a damage effect, what is it then?

Comment: @joern "kind" is not an attribute that effects have in Magic

Comment: Okay. If it is not possible to categorize this any further, then I accept this answer. "life loss" appears to be a self-contained concept.

Comment: Personally I think you have quoted the wrong rule to answer his question

Comment: 118.3. If an effect causes a player to gain life or lose life, that player’s life total is adjusted accordingly.

Comment: @Wouter The question was about No Mercy which says damage, so I went with the rule that had both terms.

Answer (score 0):

No. Loss of life is not damage - damage causes loss of life. Blood Scrivener will not cause No Mercy to trigger.